# Importing Azure Rm gives me an error

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I have a windows 7 Professional SP1 machine and have installed the windows azure poweshell version 3.7.0 and also have installed the azure rm successfully. But whenever i am trying to import the Azure Rm via the admin login i get the following error

```
PS C:\Users\swagh> Import-Module AzureRM


Import-Module : File C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureRM\4.2.1\AzureRM.psm1 cannot b
its operation is blocked by software restriction policies, such as those created by using Group Pol
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module AzureRM
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [Import-Module], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

I have tried several ways, uninstalling and reinstalling etc...but failed. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is right there in the error message, though it's not copied completely from the Powershell console:

> Import-Module : ...
>   **its operation is blocked by software restriction policies**, such as those created by using Group Pol

This means that a domain [SRP](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782792(v=ws.10).aspx) prevents you loading the module. Contact your domain administrator to discuss [SRP settings](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831534(v=ws.11).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But our admin is not able to figure out as to which setting he needs to look at. We are using the Windows 7  professional SP1 OS. if you can send us the path of the setting will be more useful...

Comment: Since i am running the scripts on my local, I opened the local security policy and then looked at the Software restriction policy which shows as none. Means there is no software restriction policy applied to my machine...So is there any way i need to look further.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this you need to change the execution policy by this simple command:

PS c:> Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

then reply Y(yes) to the popup to change setting. Now try running again the import command, it will run:

PS c:> Import-Module AzureRM

this worked for me , i hope it helps you too